# Using a DLL with Qt in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, qt

I'm trying to use a DLL with a Qt project in Visual Studio. Normally to use a DLL, it is put in the program's executable directory. However, after putting the DLL in just about every directory I could think of, it is still not being used by the program. Is there anything extra that I need to do aside from putting the DLL in the executable directory? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The dll should be in the working directory of the executable.  This is listed under the "Debugging" section of the Project Properties.

Almost all of the Qt plugin directories need to be in a specific folder next to the exe for it to be found (imageformats, platforms, etc).

Another way to find out if you are in the right directory is to add this line to your main.cpp:

```
#include <QDir>
#include <QDebug>

qDebug() << "Current Directory:" << QDir::currentPath();
```

Hope that helps.

PS also look at the order of dll search directories for windows.  <strike>I'll post more later about it.</strike> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx#search_order_for_desktop_applications